# Spark create a row containing a sum for every column (like a grand total for every column)

Tags: python, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe that looks like this

```
+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|salesperson|     device|amount_sold|
+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|       john|   notebook|          2|
|       gary|   notebook|          3|
|       john|small_phone|          2|
|       mary|small_phone|          3|
|       john|large_phone|          3|
|       john|     camera|          3|
+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

and I have transformed it using `pivot` function to this with a `Total` column

```
+-----------+------+-----------+--------+-----------+-----+
|salesperson|camera|large_phone|notebook|small_phone|Total|
+-----------+------+-----------+--------+-----------+-----+
|       gary|     0|          0|       3|          0|    3|
|       mary|     0|          0|       0|          3|    3|
|       john|     3|          3|       2|          2|   10|
+-----------+------+-----------+--------+-----------+-----+
```

but I would like a dataframe with a row (**Total**) that would also contain a total for every column like below:

```
+-----------+------+-----------+--------+-----------+-----+
|salesperson|camera|large_phone|notebook|small_phone|Total|
+-----------+------+-----------+--------+-----------+-----+
|       gary|     0|          0|       3|          0|    3|
|       mary|     0|          0|       0|          3|    3|
|       john|     3|          3|       2|          2|   10|
|      Total|     3|          3|       5|          5|   16|
+-----------+------+-----------+--------+-----------+-----+
```

Is it possible to do this is Spark using Scala/Python? (Preferably Scala and using Spark) and not using Union if possible

TIA

Comment: Did you try using `sum` function? I am guessing you already have second dataframe

Comment: Please check the last two tables, there seems to be a copy/paste problem. Also, please show your code of how you tried to solve this or any kind of effort trying to solve this problem.

Comment: Sorry there was a copy/paste problem in the second table and I have corrected it now. The third table contains a `Total` row and that is what I am after. I want to know if there is a way to add a row with a sum of every column (not by using union which I think should be possible)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like below:

```
val columns = df.columns.dropWhile(_ == "salesperson").map(col)

//Use function `sum` on each column and union the result with original DataFrame.
val withTotalAsRow = df.union(df.select(lit("Total").as("salesperson") +: columns.map(sum):_*)) 

//I think this column already exists in DataFrame
//Append another column by adding value from each column
val withTotalAsColumn = withTotalAsRow.withColumn("Total", columns.reduce(_ plus _))
```

Comment: thank you this answer works (I don't need to use the third statement) but I was looking for something that doesn't use Union if that is even possible.
I want to find out if in Spark we can add a row without using union (I know column can be added)

Comment: I don't think it is possible to generate a new DataFrame with all existing rows in it and one newly added row (which is an aggregation of all existing rows).

Answer (score 0):

With spark Scala, you can achieve this using following snippet of code.

```scala
// Assuming spark session available as variable named 'spark'
import spark.implicits._
val resultDF = df.withColumn("Total", sum($"camera", $"large_phone", $"notebook", $"small_phone"))
```